# Find number of check-boxes on webpage, when page source contains 'type' as a string also, using selenium python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code which finds number of check-boxes on the current webpage

```
checkboxes=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH("html/body/div[2]/div/section[8]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']"))
```

but it gives following error:

> 'str' object is not callable
>
> As HTML DOM contains string "checkbox" in it.

Thus I am unable to find a way to calculate total number of check-boxes.

Comment: Where is your HTML ?

Comment: Check the Andersson's answer and instead of your long xpath, you can write simply: "//input[@type='checkbox']" which finds all check boxes on a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send two arguments to `find_elements`, like `checkboxes=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)` while there is only one argument in your code- `checkboxes=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH(xpath))`. So you should use:

```
checkboxes=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "html/body/div[2]/div/section[8]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']")
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding OP comment: If you want to get only checkboxes visible on page, use following code:

```
checkboxes_list = [check for check in driver_find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox"]') if check.is_displayed()]
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I am able to count the number of checkboxes using:  checkboxes=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']" ....                                  len(checkboxes)             It gives me answer as 186...      as there are total 186 checkboxes.But on the current webpage there are 41 checkboxes visible. .so how should i select any one of the desired checkbox from this 41? By using this driver.find_elements_by_xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/section[8]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[40]/td[1]/input")                  I am able to select 40th checkkbox and so on......

Comment: @KaranPatel, Welcome

Comment: Now I am getting number of checkboxes that are currently visible i.e.(51 and it changes because its number of reports generated so it keeps on increasing), how can I use this to select any particular checkbox?

Comment: Do you want to put mark in one of displayed check-boxes? No matter which?

Comment: yes, actually I want to check the last checkbox of this page i.e. currently 51st

Comment: Use `checkboxes_list[-1].click()`